Three-person chat
Is it possible to operate a three-way chat in Salesforce?
We offer intermediary services between customers - they do not have user accounts
Sometimes customers need to communicate with each other in real time (case/chatter will not do the job)- we would like this to be done through Salesforce - to have access to the history of these conversations. In addition, sometimes we need an agent to participate in this conversation.
Has anyone met with such a solution or has an idea how to approach it?
Such a chat would be implemented in our mobile app
Initially I understand that such a chat would have to be with the use of external resources,
and then External Omnichannel routing could be used to send a three-way chat to Salesforce - in order for an agent to accept it and participate in the conversation
